# AJAX Targeting individual anchor elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP-generated table of items. Each row has a link that, when clicked, should expand the row with additional information.

I've tried using JQuery to get the data and return it, which works - but only for the first row. Every link in each row returns data into the first row only. This is because this row has a static ID, which is what I'm targeting.

I thought about trying to assign a dynamic ID when PHP generates each row by dropping a variable in there, but I'd then need to have JQuery return the id of the parent td element whenever the link is clicked so that it targets that specific row, but I don't know how to go about this.

### AJAX Function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.test").click(function(event) {
    $.post("includes/modal.php", { id: event.target.id }, function(response) {
      var ticket = document.createElement("p");
      ticket.innerText = response;
      document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(ticket);
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $('p').hide();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### PHP Generated rows and columns

```php
echo "
  <tr>
    <td>$dateChange</td>
    <td>$ticketSubject</td>
    <td id='myDiv'>
      <a class='test' type='button' href='#' id=$ticketID>
         View Ticket
      </a>
      <button>Hide</button>
    </td>
    <td>$ticketState</td>
  </tr>";
```

I would like the user to click the link on each row and have that row expand with the new data returned by the JQuery.

I can envision this working if the getElementById() part could somehow pull the appropriate column id, which would be dynamically assigned, like so:

```php
<td id=$postID>
```

I don't know if this would be the best way to go about this, but it's my current thinking. I don't know of any JQuery method that targets each unique instance clicked.

Comment: you could use an unique ID to the ROW `<tr id="<?=$postID?>">` and set classes inside of the TDs like `<td class="fieldName">` and then get/set each value thru JQuery like: `$("#postID.fieldName").innerHTML` or `$("#postID.fieldName").innerText` if you just want the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add unique  number in your div `id`  say `$ticketID`

```
echo "
<tr>
<td>$dateChange</td>
<td>$ticketSubject</td>
<td id='myDiv$ticketID'>
  <a class='test' type='button' href='#' id=$ticketID>
     View Ticket
  </a>
  <button>Hide</button>
</td>
<td>$ticketState</td>
</tr>";
```

And in your JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.test").click(function(event) {
$.post("includes/modal.php", { id: event.target.id }, function(response) {
  var ticket = document.createElement("p");
  ticket.innerText = response;
  document.getElementById('myDiv'+event.target.id).appendChild(ticket);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('p').hide();
  });
});
});
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your markup as:

```
echo "
  <tr>
    <td>$dateChange</td>
    <td>$ticketSubject</td>
    <td>
      <a class='test' type='button' href='includes/modal.php?id=$ticketID'>
         View Ticket
      </a>
      <button>Hide</button>
    </td>
    <td>$ticketState</td>
  </tr>";
```

Here, I add `href` attribute with the link to required page. Also I removed `id='myDiv'` as `id` **must be unique** on the page.

In javascript you just do a POST-request to this `href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.test").click(function(event) {
    // $(this) gives you the clicked element as jQuery object
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
      // according to your markup you can do:
      $(this).parent().append('<p>' + response + '</p>');
      // Instead of these lines below
      /*var ticket = document.createElement("p");
      ticket.innerText = response;
      document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(ticket);*/
    });
    // return false to prevent default action on `a` click
    return false;

    // I don't know what you expect when put `ready` into `ready`
    /*$(document).ready(function(){*/
      $("button").click(function(){
        $('p').hide();
      });
    /*});*/
  });
});
```

Comment: True, just wanted to make sure the OP know that they must be unique in the event they try to use them for something else.

Comment: Fixed a part with using same id, thanks @JayBlanchard